# Different ways of initializing objects in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, ios4, ios5

There are two ways of initializing objects in Objective-C, i.e.:

1) `AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];`

2) `AVCaptureSession *session = [AVCaptureSession new];`

Seems like they are doing the same job. What is the difference between them? Or "new" it is just a novelty of iOS5?

Would be grateful for the answer,

Artem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` is a shortcut way of doing an alloc/init that should work on any object, but it's mainly a hangover from Smalltalk and `new` calls never take arguments so you don't see it used much at all any more.

So the two should be identical and it's a novelty but not of iOS 5.

EDIT: further to this, [`new`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/new) is defined on `NSObject` as something that calls `alloc` and then `init` and is given as having been available since Mac OS X 10.0 (which is the beginning of time as far as Apple's documentation is concerned).

Comment: Note that many objects have designated initializers other than -init, so it's not appropriate to call -new. A prime example would be creating any type of NSView subclass (including all Cocoa controls) in code. The designated initializer is -initWithFrame: and takes a rectangle as an argument. Initializing a view with -init will give you unpredictable (and usually undesirable) results so you need the alloc/initWithFrame: pair. Lesson: Don't use -new just anywhere. :-)